# Continuous URL Data Fetch in Android

Tags: android

I want to fetch JSON data from URL continuously and display it in Realtime in an Android Page. I am not getting any idea as to how to do it.

Comment: use firebase for realtime updation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a technique called polling (fetching the data every X seconds) or use  websockets if real time is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void timerfor10Seconds() {

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do something after 30 seconds

            urlCall();
        }
    }, 10*1000);  // add timer for 10 sec
}

urlCall(){
    call api
}

on api reponse update UI and recall timerfor10Seconds()

2. Option
Use Socket.Io library for continuous data broadcast, accordingly you need to implement the same library on your server side, as calling api continuously is not a correct way to display live data.
```